# SQL server : Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql-server-2012

SQL Server : i want to convert my varchar datatype to float but i do have some scientific notation values in it(for ex. 3.11955748130297E-02) and i am getting following error : Error converting data type varchar to float.

I have tried it using convert and cast functions, but that's not working.

```
insert into table1--(data type as float) 

select convert(float,column1),-- contains '3.11955748130297E-02' as value and datatype is varchar 

convert(float,column2) 

from table2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 : Converting varchar value '1.23E-4' to decimal fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148990/sql-server-2005-converting-varchar-value-1-23e-4-to-decimal-fails)

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(float, '3.11955748130297E-02')` works for me on my SQL Server 2012 server. Can you provide the non-working code?

Comment: insert into table1--(data type as float)  
select convert(float,column1),-- contains '3.11955748130297E-02' as value and datatype is varchar
convert(float,column2)
from table2

Comment: @CodeDifferent : i have pasted the sample of the code

Comment: Are you sure `3.11...E-02` was the one that caused troubles? How about searching for the ones that do: `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2 WHERE TRY_CONVERT(float, column1) IS NULL OR TRY_CONVERT(float, column2) IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

the error was coming due to the 'column break' in one of the columns , i tried it using the below code:

convert(float,REPLACE(column1, CHAR(13), '')) column1

thanks a lot for the responses.